# Execute more than 500 operations at once in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, nosql, batch-processing, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a `WriteBatch` to keep control of one of my dynamic references in my database. My app have a simple `User-Follow-Post-Feed` model where I want my user to see in his feed the posts of all the users he is following. What I'm doing after research on Firebase examples (as [Firefeed](https://firefeed.io/) ) and a lot of posts on Stack Overflow.

The optimal idea is keep a path (`collection` in this case) where I store the `Ids` of the posts that my user should see in his feed, which means keep control of copy and delete every post of all the users that he follow/unfollow.

I made my `Cloud functions` for keep this in an atomic way, and everything is working fine, but when I tried to do a massive test, adding more than 5000 posts for an user an trying to follow him (looking for see how much time the `Cloud function` would take), I saw that batches have a limit of 500 operations. So what I did is split my 5000 id's in multiple small lists and execute one batch per list, never surpassing the 500 limit.

But even doing it on this way, I still getting an error that `I can't do more than 500 operations in a single commit`, I don't know if maybe is because the batches are executing at the same time, or why. I think that maybe I can concat one after another, and avoid execute them all at once. But I still having some troubles with it. So that's the reason of my question.

Here is my method:

```
 fun updateFeedAfterUserfollow(postIds: QuerySnapshot, userId: String) {
        //If there is no posts from the followed user, return
        if (postIds.isEmpty) return
        val listOfPostsId = postIds.map { it.id }
        val mapOfInfo = postIds.map { it.id to it.toObject(PublicUserData::class.java) }.toMap()

        //Get User ref
        val ref = firestore.collection(PRIVATE_USER_DATA).document(userId).collection(FEED)
        //Split the list in multiple list to avoid the max 500 operations per batch
        val idsPartition = Lists.partition(listOfPostsId, 400)

        //Create a batch with max 400 operations and execute it until the whole list have been updated
        idsPartition.forEach { Ids ->
            val batch = firestore.batch().also { batch ->
                Ids.forEach { id -> batch.set(ref.document(id), mapOfInfo[id]!!) }
            }
            batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful)
                    Grove.d { "Commit updated successfully" }
                else Grove.d { "Commit fail" }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: What was your end solution?

Comment: Hi francisco,  i was wondering if you could help me. I'm doing something similar in firestore a User-Follow-Post-Feed kind of thing, and i want to ask you. If you hava a user that has 5000 followers and hi makes a post, do you generate an index for that post for every follower or do you create a copy of that post for every follower. Thank you!

Comment: I would add an index for each user, yes. There si no need to add the whole post copy, because a post can be edited multiple times, and ID, not. Give a look to one of my repositories where I solve this kind of problems with cloud functions https://github.com/FrangSierra/firestore-cloud-functions-typescript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally the problem was caused because I was trying to realize this batch operations inside a transaction, which also acts like a batch in the end. That's why even I was generating batches for each 400 references, these instances were created inside a transaction and it counts like a single big transaction which surpass the 500 limit.

I made a few changes and implemented on a repository on my GitHub.

```
//Generate the right amount of batches
    const batches = _.chunk(updateReferences, MAX_BATCH_SIZE)
        .map(dataRefs => {
            const writeBatch = firestoreInstance.batch();
            dataRefs.forEach(ref => {
                writeBatch.update(ref, 'author', newAuthor);
            });
            return writeBatch.commit();
        });
```

It is written in typescript, but you will understand it for sure:
https://github.com/FrangSierra/firestore-cloud-functions-typescript/blob/master/functions/src/atomic-operations/index.ts

Comment: sometimes generating batches for 150 references is throwing "deadline exceeded" error. Do u have any suggestion for it?

Comment: are you throwing them concurrently? or 1 by 1

Comment: Francisco in this example of 5000 items, is the function completing 500 in a batch commit...then moving on to the next 500? Or is it executing 10 batches simultaneously (each 500, and therefor 5000 at once)?

Comment: Instead of "return writeBatch.commit();", If we do "await writeBatch.commit();" it may not hit any limitations right?

Comment: await writeBatch.commit() would still hit the limitation. Its because its in a map and Promise.all. You would need to put it in a for loop with an await (not a foreach, because promises don't work the way you think they do). Doing this will insure its one after another.